# What to do if we want a input format for select options of a webform?

Tags: webforms, theming

I have a web form with select option field whose value is quite long. I cannot use css to configure this. I need to use input format so that I can break this option using HTML code. Is there any module or something?

**Additional Info:**
We don't have input format option in case of webform module's select fields. My value in select field option is quite long. I have three values like below:

```
  Session 1: PwC 
  11:30am
  Sourcing Strategies for the Next Decade

  Presented by:
  Damon Paling, Partner, PwC China
  Anthony Tennariello, Partner, PwC New York
  Maytee Pereira, Director, PwC New York.
```

I would like show the user like this but this is not possible since we don't have input format (HTML) to select.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the chosen module.

https://drupal.org/project/chosen

Its goal is to make input element a little more user friendly.

See here: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: But I don't want user friendly select value. I want to break select option values which is quite long.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the form field looks like and how you would like it to look/function.

Comment: Please check my updated question.